# Send some data from child to parent component before render in blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

i'm trying to create a ChildComponent that send some data to ParentComponent before Parent will render itself.
Firstly i try to send reference of Parent to all ChildComponents and than i try to set easy text in ParentComponent directly from Childs using value of parameters.
Could someone tell me, why code belowe doesn't work?
Thaks to everyone for any help!

Main file:

```
@page "/test"

<h3>TestTabeli</h3>
<ParentComponent>
    <ChildComponent Name="Child nr 1" />
    <ChildComponent Name="Child nr 2" />
</ParentComponent>
```

Parent File:

```
<h3>ParentComponent</h3>

<CascadingValue Value="Parent" Name="ParentRef">
    @body
</CascadingValue>

<br />
<p>My Childrens: @text</p>

@code {
    public string text { get; set; } = "blaaaa";
    public ParentComponent Parent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
        base.OnInitialized();
        Parent = this;
        }
    public RenderFragment body { get; set; }

    }
```

Child Component:

```
<h3>ChildComponent</h3>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Child Name";

    [CascadingParameter(Name = "ParentRef")]
    public ParentComponent parent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
        {
        base.OnParametersSet();
        parent.text += "<br /> Hi! My name is: " + Name;
            
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> create a ChildComponent that send some data to ParentComponent before Parent
> will render itself

That is not possible. Can a woman produce a child before she is born. But you'll see later on that we can deceive the human eyes to believe this is possible. But your question is the reasons why your code is not working, right ?

```
<CascadingValue Value="Parent" Name="ParentRef">
    @body
</CascadingValue>
```

This is the first reason why your code won't execute. You must use, `@ChildContent` rather than `@body`.

You should also have this in code:

```
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
```

Note that you must add the  [Parameter] attribute.

After making some additional changes to your code, it may work:

### ParentComponent.razor

```
@page "/ParentComponent"

<h3>ParentComponent</h3>

<CascadingValue Value="this" Name="ParentRef">
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

<br />
<p>My Childrens: @text</p>

@code {
    public string text { get; set; } = "blaaaa";
  //  public ParentComponent Parent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
      //  Parent = this;
    }
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

}
```

### ChildComponent.razor

```
<h3>@Name</h3>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Child Name";

    [CascadingParameter(Name = "ParentRef")]
    public ParentComponent parent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
         parent.text += "Hi! My name is: " + Name;

    }
}
```

Copy and run that code. Note that the text in the text property won't change. It'll always display the string "blaaaa". The solution to this is to use an EventCallback to pass a new value to the Text property as well as to re-render the parent component.

Generally speaking, the use of the CascadingValue component is not appropriate. And you should not pass a reference to the parent component to the child component. You should usually use component parameters and events (EventCallback 'delegate') to handle the relations between parent and children

Answer (score 0):

You can not render child component inside parentcomponent straightly. Instead you need to use Template parameters, A templated component is defined by specifying one or more component parameters of type RenderFragment or RenderFragment. A render fragment represents a segment of UI to render. RenderFragment takes a type parameter that can be specified when the render fragment is invoked. something like this :

```
@typeparam TItem

    @foreach (var item in Items)
    {
       @ChildTemplate(item)
    }
```

@code {

```
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment<TItem> ChildTemplate { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public IReadOnlyList<TItem> Items { get; set; }
```

}

the template parameters can be specified using child elements that match the names of the parameters.
take a look at [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0)